# Compare two dates using Date component only disregarding time

Tags: datetime, luxon

In C#, typically you can use `DateTime.Today` to get today's date disregarding the time component (e.g. the time component would be at midnight basically).

How do I do that using Luxom library?

I understand you can write `DateTime.local()` to get a Date object with current Time included, but is there no simple way to effectively disregard the time component so that I can perform a comparison with another Date object?

I can't find any relevant information in the Luxon documentation, though I may have missed something.

In standard JS, this would do it:

```
new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0));
```

But that seems awkward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`startOf('day')`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html#instance-method-startOf) to set midnight to given `DateTime`:

> "Set" this DateTime to the beginning of a unit of time.

then you can use [`toJSDate()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html#instance-method-toJSDate) to get the equivalent Javascript Date or other method like [`toISO`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html#instance-method-toISO), [`toISODate()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html#instance-method-toISODate), [`toFormat()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html#instance-method-toFormat) etc to get the string representation of  a `DateTime`.

Example:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
console.log( DateTime.local().startOf('day').toJSDate() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.25.0/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```

If you need to compare Luxon objects have a look at [Comparing DateTimes](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/math.html#comparing-datetimes) section of the manual.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.local().toISODate();
```

This gave me what I wanted.